# Can I get the PID of program launched by a subprogram?

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

My python script runs a program, let's call it X.exe

```
from subprocess import Popen
process = Popen('D:X.exe')
```

I can get its PID via

```
process.pid
```

After some time (which I know) X.exe launches another program - Y.exe. Can I get the PID of the Y.exe process? NOTE: I DON'T KNOW WHAT THE Y.exe WINDOW WILL BE NAMED

Comment: I think the only way to find the child processes of a given process is to iterate over *all* processes, and then select those that have your target process as a parent. That's effectively how tools like `pgrep` work.

Comment: ...and that's something you'd need to go beyond the Python standard library to do; you could use [`psutil`](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/), f/e.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you very much, it was very helpful, what if X.exe calls Y.exe not as a subprocess but as a separate program?

Comment: Starting a separate program _does_ start a subprocess. The way one program starting another program _works_ is that you first `fork()`, creating a child in the process tree, and then inside that child you run `execve()`, replacing it with a separate piece of software. There are newer syscalls like `spawn()`, but the effect is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can see the children of a process using [psutil](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/) simply as follows.

```py
import psutil
import subprocess
import time

proc = subprocess.Popen("start /wait", shell=True)  # start another cmd.exe

time.sleep(0.5)  # wait for child to start
process_object = psutil.Process(proc.pid)
children = process_object.children()
print(f"child pid is {children[0].pid}")
proc.wait()
```

```
child pid is 18292
```

Comment: thank you, but what if X.exe calls Y.exe not as a subprocess but as a separate program? Is it possible?

Comment: Subprocesses _are_ separate programs, as long as there's an `execve()` or equivalent boundary between it and its parent.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy what about detached processes `DETACHED_PROCESS | CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP` ? they aren't children of the process in the perspective of the OS, there are ways to listen to its creation call on the win32api, but i don't know the exact details ...

Comment: You'd need to talk to someone who lives in the Windows world, but in the UNIX world being in a new process group doesn't prevent you from still having your parent process point to the process that created you, and `DETACHED_PROCESS` isn't a thing.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes, you are correct, detaching a process doesn't seem to affect pstuils asking for children either, so the answer here is that `psutil` will work regardless of the creation method.